# Почему не накладывается текстура в Substance Painter?

Tags: 3d, substance-painter

Пытаюсь наложить текстуру - рядом с текстурой появляется значок и ничего не происходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы нашли решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

С наскока в Пейнтере не разобраться. Надо смотреть туториалы (хотя бы вводные, минут на 25).

В двух словах - по умолчанию созданный слой предназначен для рисования кистью по модели. А рисует кисть материалом сразу во множество каналов. Поэтому просто текстуру Пейнтер не сообразит на что нацепить. Но вы можете навесить текстуру на компонент кисти (см. справа внизу под ползунками кисти есть каналы, и вот туда-то её можно "дропнуть". Это будет рисунок кисти - вряд ли то что вам нужно.

Чтобы наложить текстуру на UV - добавляйте новый слой Fill и в его канал "дропайте" свою текстуру (например в "Base color").

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]